# TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable python

Tags: python, typeerror

```
for i in range(0,10):
    res_lsq = np.sqrt(np.mean((polynomial_fit(lambda i: 'theta' + str(i), xtr) - ytr)**2))
    rmse.append(res_lsq)
```

I'm finding the root mean square error for each of the Mth degree polynomial fitting a curve using the least-squares method. I want to vary the weight parameters i.e theta from theta0 to theta9 (float values) in my polynomial_fit function to append the RMSE for each mth degree polynomial into the rmse list. But it is showing error as follows

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-4e717fdd943a> in <module>
      1 for i in range(0,10):
----> 2     res_lsq = np.sqrt(np.mean((polynomial_fit(lambda i: 'theta' + str(i), xtr) - ytr)**2))
      3     rmse.append(res_lsq)

<ipython-input-20-d7d3539688a0> in polynomial_fit(theta, x)
      1 def polynomial_fit(theta, x):
      2     """Polynomial model of degree (len(theta) - 1)"""
----> 3     return sum(t * x ** n for (n, t) in enumerate(theta))

TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You're passing a lambda function to `polynomial_fit` which accepts an iterable as its first argument.

Comment: It seems like `theta` is expected to be a list of numeric types, too - you're attempting to pass a string.

Comment: theta is float values

Comment: If you replace `lambda i: 'theta' + str(i)` with your list of floats then this will at least not throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, there is different errors in your code:

`np.mean` expects an array (an iterable) as first argument. But you are passing a function `polynomial_fit` that returns a sum.
it will not throw any error to give an int or a float to `np.mean` but a this is of little use. In general you want, for example, to get the mean of [1,2,3,4] (== 2.5 ), not "4".

The function `polynomial_fit` contains `enumerate(theta)`, but `theta` is NOT iterable, so you get an error of type `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`.

And this is related to the content of the lambda function, which statement is written as a string, as @erip said.

Comment: Sorry, but this analysis is not correct. `polynomial_fit` is the error-inducing invocation.

Comment: Ah, I think  expressed myself poorly (not completely fluent in english), I'll correct my answer to be more clear. Thank you for pointing that.

Comment: Your English is fine, but your diagnosis is not. If you remove the call to `np.mean`, the OP will still observe the error.

Comment: I think I understand you but expressed it poorly, I've just edited my answer.